# MySQL Searching forename and surname

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

OK, I have a DB table that's called `players` and each player has a forename and surname. Then I have a PHP Ajax search thing that I call to search for players. For example... in the input box, someone types `James` and there's a row in the table with forename and surname `James` and `Smith` respetively.

I do this `$check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM`players`WHERE`surname`LIKE '%$name%' OR`forename`LIKE '%$name%' LIMIT 0, 10") or die(mysql_error());`

And it returns at least 10 with either forename or surname `like` the keyword `James`. However, if I type `James Smith`, despite it being in the table, I get zero results.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using InnoDB or MyISAM?  If your using MyISAM, you can create a single field which holds the combined name and then search it using a full text index.  So lets imagine you add a new field called combined_names you would search it like this

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE match(combined_names) against('John Smith');
```

This would find any row with either John or Smith in, you can change it to match only those rows with both parts you would add plusses like so:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE match(combined_names) against('+John +Smith');
```

Here is the documentation on the MySQL site where you can find out more:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html

Comment: But.. wouldn't the field `combined_names` need to have data inside to search it?

Comment: Well, yes, you would need to populate this either within your code or within a trigger.  Does this duplicate data.... yes, but sometimes duplicated data is the best way to get search performance. You can use other code solutions to split the string and do a number of ors etc, you have a fixed amount of complication in your application, your choice is where you put it :).

Comment: Question @Scott Neville... how it come only works for longer texts? I tried searching `Gao Li` from `Gao Lin` and it didn't work.. when other (longer) names did work..

Comment: Sorry its taken me so long to reply.  MySQL has a some configuration parameters on it to control the full text search, these are:
ft_min_word_len - This by default is 4 and it means only words longer than 4 characters are searchable, change this in the my.cnf (if you change it you will need to rebuild the index, simplest way it to drop and recreate it).
The other is stop words you can find out more here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-stopwords.html

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM players WHERE CONCAT(forename, ' ', surname) = '$name' OR forename LIKE '%$name%' OR surname LIKE '%$name%'
```

Comment: This is good. Thank you. However, it only seems to work when I type `John Smith`... where as (since I'm doing ajax search and on keypress) searching for `John Smi` returns 0...

Comment: Then just do a LIKE: `CONCAT(forename, ' ', surname) LIKE '%$name%'` . Or, for better database performance, `CONCAT(forename, ' ', surname) LIKE '$name%'` (assuming you are using indexes)

Answer (score 1):

split the name up on spaces so the query runs twice (if there is one space)

the query will run for both names

```
$nameBits = explode($name," ");
```

run the query for each piece of $nameBits

```
surname LIKE '%$nameBits[$i]%'
```